# foreignkey error in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I get the following error when trying to build my database using db_create.py. According to the documentation when you use backref it is supposed to add a foreignkey to the other class, but for some reason it's not.

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Message.users - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

models.py

```
class Message(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    message=db.Column(db.String(69), unique=True, nullable=False)
    timestamp=db.Column(db.DateTime)

    #Problem Code below
    users=db.relationship('Message_User', backref='message', lazy='dynamic')
    children=db.relationship('Message_Group', backref='message', lazy='dynamic')
    #group backrefs Group

class Message_User(db.Model):
    __tablename__='message_user'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    acknowledge=db.Column(db.DateTime, default=False)
    timestamp=db.Column(db.DateTime)
    #group backrefs Message_Group
    #message backrefs Message
```

db_createpy

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path
db.create_all()
if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO,
                        api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

Comment: I don't think `backref` automatically creates foreign keys. You still have to add the corresponding `ForeignKey` columns. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html

Comment: A backref automatically adds a back referencing relationship property, not a foreign key. Foreign keys are a relational DB concept, relationship properties an ORM concept.